# Popen gives "File not found" Error (windows/python)

Tags: python, windows, popen

I'm trying to run console commands via **subprocess.Popen**, and whenever I run it I get the windows "File not found" error, even when running the echo command.
I am also using Popen inside a thread made with the thread module. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of
`D:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\terabytest\sourcesdk\bin\orangebox\bin\vbsp.exe`, use
`D:/Program Files/Steam/steamapps/terabytest/sourcesdk/bin/orangebox/bin/vbsp.exe`

This eliminates any complications with backslashes inside quotes.

Comment: Another major source of the problem is whitespace inside the path. It is much more robust to use a list of parameters instead of a string. Try to do something like Popen(["D:/Program Files/Steam/steamapps/terabytest/sourcesdk/bin/orangebox/bin/vbsp.exe", "param1", "param2"])

Answer (score 3):

`echo` is not an executable, it's an internal command inside `cmd.exe`. If you want to use Popen with internal commands, add a keyword parameter `shell=True`

Comment: I put in
'"D:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\terabytest\sourcesdk\bin\orangebox\bin\vbsp.exe"'

and I still get errors, it doesn't work with either shell=True or shell=False

Why?

Comment: try escaping the backslashes (with another backslash)